# I want to create this command for my discord bot that stores a list of messages that a bunch of users say then have a command to randomly choose them

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For more detail I would like to create a command for my bot that takes in messages stores it somewhere like in a new file or something like that and have a new command send a message from that new file. I am wondering if I should use json or make a .txt file.

My Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content == "echo":
        echomessage = (message.content)
        await message.channel.send(f"{echomessage} has been added to a list of messages")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} {echomessage[random.randint(0, len(echomessage) - 1)]}")
```

I know that I have a event I would like to make it a command at some point but if I cant then imma just keep it as it.

Thanks for anyone who takes a shot at helping me! I really appriciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save it to a file and randomly pick one.

Using `readlines`, simply write each word to use into its own line, and a random one will be picked automatically.

```py
@bot.command()
async def addword(ctx, *, word: str):
    with open('words.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{word}\n')

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(5, 20.0, commands.BucketType.guild)  # Highly recommended, io is precious. You can also keep this file permanently opened and store it in your client at startup.
async def echo(ctx):
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        await ctx.send(random.choice(f.readlines()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it im pretty new to coding discord bots ive only been doing it for like 9 months now and I know I have a lot to learn